# Alternative to REGEXP_INSTR in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Do we have an Alternative function to REGEXP_INSTR in Bigquery as this function is not available in Bigquery.

An example of where we are using REGEXP_INSTR :

I have a invoice_number column which has values like "123A45", "54B381", "1A2B21" etc, I need to find the position of the first occurrence of the alphabet from these values. In this case it would be 4,3 and 2 respectively. We have used Regexp_instr function for this. Can we achieve the same functionality using Regexp_Contains or any other alternative method ?

Thanks
Thirumalai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT invoice_number, 
  LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT(invoice_number, r'^(\d*)[^\d]')) + 1 AS first_occurrence_of_the_alphabet 
FROM t
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - the output is

```
Row invoice_number  first_occurrence_of_the_alphabet     
1   123A45          4    
2   54B381          3    
3   1A2B21          2
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, is the above function equivalent to this : regexp_instr(INVOICE_NUM,'[A-Z]',1,1) ?

Comment: in your case - looks like it is

Answer (score 0):

It's called [REGEXP_CONTAINS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains)

```
SELECT
  email,
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(email, r"@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+") AS is_valid
FROM
  (SELECT
    ["foo@example.com", "bar@example.org", "www.example.net"]
    AS addresses),
  UNNEST(addresses) AS email;
```

Comment: I have a invoice_number column which has values like "123A45", "54B381", "1A2B21" etc, I need to find the position of the first occurrence of the alphabet from these values. In this case it would be 4,3 and 2 respectively. We have used Regexp_instr function for this. Can we achieve the same functionality using Regexp_Contains ?

Comment: You're asking a different question now. Perhaps open a new one, or edit your original question with these new details.

Comment: OK I will edit the question with these details. Thanks.